# router-link-active Nuxt 3 / VueJS on nested routes not applying to parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3

I have created a simple reproduction to better explain myself. I have:

```
-| pages/
---| test/
------| index.vue
------| nested.vue
```

And I have a navbar, having read the documentation I assume if I NuxtLink to `/test` or `/test/nested.vue` then I would have `router-link-active` css class applied to both in the navbar but it doesn't seem to do that.

The docs seem to suggest you should be laying out your content as:

```
-| pages/
---| parent/
------| child.vue
---| parent.vue
```

I tried that and just doesn't work - the child is never rendered (unless I add another `<NuxtPage>` to parent.vue which is not what I want since that would show content of parent and child.

Reproduction here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-app-config-t3nvjv?file=app.vue

Help would be much appreciated appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I faced exactly the same issue and finally understood how to use `NuxtPage`!

You must follow the following structure:

```
/pages
  /posts
    [postId].vue
    index.vue
  posts.vue
```

In your `/posts/index.vue`:

```
<template>
  <h1>All posts page</h1>
  <p>Whatever...</p>
</template>
```

In your `/posts/[postId].vue`:

```
<template>
  <h1>Single post page</h1>
  <p>{{ postId }}</p>
</template>
```

And finally, in your `posts.vue`:

```
<template>
  <NuxtPage />
</template>
```

Both your `index.vue` and `[postId].vue` content will be rendered separately and your `NuxtLink`s `router-link-active` and `router-link-exact-active` classes will work :)

Comment: Coming from Nuxt 2 thinking, the top-level `posts.vue` was what I was missing to make routes properly nest so that the activeClass actually applies.