Nuxt 3 child route with dynamic parameter not getting active-class
I have the following folder structure. And the following pages are of important
/workshops and /workshops/workshop-1.
The issue I'm having now is that my active-link works for /workshops, but not for the subroutes.
I know I can add the workshops.vue file to my folder structure, as noted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74748684/1731057
Which then has
<template>
    <NuxtPage />
</template>

However there is currently a page /workshops, that is being caught by the [slug].vue, which is intended. When I add this new workshops.vue page, my [slug] page is not catching this anymore.
How can I get the active-link to work, while also keeping the [slug].vue route for the /workshops path?
This is my folder structure

pages

workshops

[workshop].vue


[slug].vue
workshops.vue <--- when adding this my [slug].vue doesn't catch /workshops anymore




"However there is currently a page /workshops, that is being caught by the [slug].vue", this is not a good thing it is not supposed to. Do you want to have a /workshops and /workshops/2 to be together? I would hence have a workshops directory with index.vue and [id].vue as showcased here, don't have an outside workshops.vue because it will override/short-circuit the whole convention. As for the active-class itself, once you have the usual structure, check your vue-router details thanks to the Vue devtools.

@kissu But that would mean I have a workshops/index.vue, which is separate from my [slug].vue, the idea is that the [slug].vue should catch this page, since it uses my page builder. Thanks

<template>
<NuxtLink to="/about" :class="activePage === `infos` ? 'router-link-active' : ''">
 ABOUT
</NuxtLink>
</template>

<script setup>
const route = useRoute();
const activePage = computed(() => {
  if (route.path) return route.path.split('/')[1];
  return '';
});
</script>


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
